# Como executar arquivo bat pelo delphi

Tags: delphi, bat

Pessoal estou tentando executar um arquivo bat que está na mesma pasta do exe, porém tentei de várias maneiras e ele não executa.

```
WinExec('startNodeJS.bat',SW_SHOW);
```

Não executa o bat, esse bat é para iniciar o servidor nodejs, tanto que se eu ir manual no bat e clicar duas vezes ele abre o dos e iniciar o nodejs, mas pelo delphi, ele pisca o dos e não faz nada, o comando do bat é :

```
cd E:\socket
node server.js
```

Já coloquei o bat na past e:\socket e também tentei executar pelo delphi assim :

```
WinExec('e:\socket\startNodeJS.bat',SW_SHOW);
```

mas também não foi pelo delphi, alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoque o interpretador de comando **`cmd.exe`**

```bat
WinExec('cmd.exe /c "e:\socket\startNodeJS.bat"',SW_SHOW);
```

```bat
cmd.exe /c = executa comando/bat e fecha/close
```

```bat
cmd.exe  /k = executa comando/bat e mantém/keep
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, fiz o ajuste mas continuava dando erro, então percebi que o nodejs não estava no path do windows, ai ele dava como não reconhecido o comando node, após incluir no path, funcionou corretamente.

Comment: @RobinhodeMorais Muito boa a sua sacada.

Comment: Valeu obrigado.